# asp.net: When is the Visible property of child controls automatically set?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, textbox, viewstate

**Example 1:**

```
<asp:Panel Visible="false" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Here, `textbox.Visible` returns `false` in code (even though `TextBox.Visible` was not set explicitly; it seem to "inherit" the property from its invisible parent).

**Example 2:**

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn Visible="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="textbox" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
    ...
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Here, `((TextBox)grid.Items[0].FindControl("textbox")).Visible` returns `true` (under the assumption that the DataGrid has at least one row).

---

**Question:** Is this inconsistent behaviour by design? In both cases, the TextBox is not rendered because some parent element is invisible.

(Granted, in the second case the textbox is inside a template, but I'm not querying an abstract TextBox in the template definition, I'm querying the specific, concrete TextBox in row number 0.)

**Background:** TextBox is a smart control: [It only saves its Text property in the ViewState if it's invisible.](http://couldbedone.blogspot.com/2007/07/hidden-controls-and-viewstate.html) That makes sense: If the TextBox is visible, it's rendered as a HTML `<input>` control and its current `Text` value is submitted on a postback - no need to submit it again via the ViewState. Of course, if the TextBox is invisible, it is not rendered, and, thus, any changes to the `Text` property would be lost.

Now, Example 2 is giving us some trouble. `textbox` thinks that it's being rendered (according to IL spy, it checks its own `Visible` property in `TextBox.SaveTextViewState`), so it doesn't use the ViewState and all changes to `textbox.Text` done in code are lost. I'm now wondering whether this is bug or not.

---

**Related question:** [How to get the set/real value of the Visible property in Asp.Net.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005322/how-to-get-the-set-real-value-of-the-visible-property-in-asp-net)

---

**EDIT:** I've created a Microsoft Connect Bug Report on this:

- [Webforms: Control.Visible does not recognize that the control is within an invisible DataGrid column](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/679496)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TextBox` and `Panel` both inherit from `WebControl`, which inherits from `Control`. `Control` has the following definition for the `Visible` property:

```
public virtual bool Visible
{
    get
    {
        return !this.flags[16] &&
               (this._parent == null || this.DesignMode || this._parent.Visible);
    }
    set
    {
        if (this.flags[2])
        {
            bool flag = !this.flags[16];
            if (flag != value)
            {
                this.flags.Set(32);
            }
        }
        if (!value)
        {
            this.flags.Set(16);
            return;
        }
        this.flags.Clear(16);
    }
}
```

Since `Visible` is not implemented directly on `TextBox`, it will always return `false` if the `Visible` property of the parent is false (at runtime and if there is a parent specified). So to answer the question asked in the title, the `Visible` property is not automatically set to `false` at any point in time, it's just evaluated when it is accessed.  In the case of the `GridView` where `TextBox.Visible` returns `true`, it stands to reason that the parent control of the `TextBox` is not the `TemplateColumn`, or at least the parent does not have its `Visible` property set to false.

**EDIT**
So, using your example grid in the question, if you walk the chain of controls up, you'll see that all of the parent controls for the `TextBox` are `Visible`. I used the code below, and here's the output:

```
TextBox (ClientID = grid_textbox_0, Visible = True)
TableCell (ClientID = grid_ctl00_0, Visible = True)
DataGridItem (ClientID = grid, Visible = True)
ChildTable (ClientID = grid_ctl00, Visible = True)
DataGrid (ClientID = grid, Visible = True)
HtmlForm (ClientID = form1, Visible = True)
```

Code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var control = grid.Items[0].FindControl("textbox");
    while(control != this && control != null)
    {
        Response.Write(string.Format("{0} (ClientID = {1}, Visible = {2})",
            control.GetType().Name, control.ClientID, control.Visible));
        Response.Write("<br />");
        control = control.Parent;
    }
}
```

It seems to me that the `DataGrid` and the `Visisble` properties are working as expected.

Comment: +1, thanks for the explanation. I'll wait a bit before accepting it as an answer, since I'm still curious about why exactly this fails to work in Example 2. After all, the code you show recursively calls `_parent.Visible`, so it should suffice if there's *any* hidden control up the parent tree, not just the direct parent.

Comment: @Heinzi I'll try to take a closer look at example 2 later today. Maybe GridView has it's own Visible implementation or something.

Comment: @Heinzi I updated my answer to show why the TextBox is showing as Visible in your second example. One thing I'm confused about though, how is the value of the TextBox changing if the TemplateColumn is not visible? Are you saying that you are setting the TextBox to a value when the grid is databound and then you can't read it back out on PostBack?

Comment: Thanks, that's very interesting! I don't think that the TableCell should have Visible=True, though, since it is definitely not rendered (so I guess the "bug" is in there). About the TextBox thing: Yes, I'm changing the value of the `Text` property in code. Since the Textbox thinks that it's visible, it does not persist the value into the ViewState, thus, the value is lost on the next postback.

Comment: @Heinzi I agree, you can definitely make the argument that the `TableCell` should have `Visible=false`. A workaround for this problem is to use a different control to store the value, like `asp:Label` (or the `CommandArgument` attribute if there is a button handy). The `Label` should have its value persisted on postback.

Comment: @Heinzi My mistake in the previous comment, I think an `asp:Literal` control would be the one to use, not `asp:Label`.