# VisibleChanged don't raise when not visible

Tags: c#, winforms, visibility

I'm working on c# WinForm.

I have an custom UserControl : `MyControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged`. I attached a method on event on event VisibleChanged : `this.VisibleChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.MyControl_VisibleChanged);`

My application have some pages, each page is a control like `MyControl`. Top of MainWindows contains Button, used to switch tab.

My problem is that my function `MyControl_VisibleChanged` is called only when Visible is changing to true. I added a test in a tab to check `MyControl.Visible`, when I select the other tab, `MyControl.Visible` is `false` but no event is raised.

I've try to define a new property Visible for this control but value is never set, only the `base` value is modify.

Can you help me to find a solution ?

Comment: I am having the same issue.  I get the callback any time it becomes visible but never when it goes invisible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a quirk in the way `Visible` works, [explained here](http://blog.excastle.com/2004/10/18/controlvisible-ugh/). His solution was to use properties that he has complete control over, but you could instead have a method allowing the tab switches to tell their children to raise their `VisibleChanged` event that extra time.

The first two answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391888/how-to-get-the-real-value-of-the-visible-property) may also be useful.

Comment: As I read them, all of these references are discussing the fact that the visibility is taking the parent's state into account.  I don't think that's the issue the OP has having.  I am experiencing the same thing he is and it is simply a refusal of the VisibleChanged callback to fire except when Visibility = true.  Any time it goes false the callback is not called.

Comment: @JohnFairbanks I've tested and confirmed that if you try it with controls directly on a form (ie. no parent controls other than the form itself), then VisibleChanged works fine for setting both true & false. So it's an issue with a parent's state. If you put the controls on parent panels and show/hide the parents instead, that's when the child's VisibleChanged only fires on true. However, making things visible in careful order may be an option: hide children individually before hiding parent and VisibleChanged will fire on false. To show again, set visible on parent before showing children.

Comment: you are correct!  Sorry my mistake!  I had it embedded in a tab control.

Answer (score 2):

The `Control.Visible` property is an odd one insofar as its set-accessor sets a value local to the control to which you have no access, but the get-accessor returns the net effect of this hidden value in this control and all its parents.

Furthermore, neither the `OnVisibleChanged` nor `OnParentVisibleChanged` virtual methods (or their corresponding events) trigger quite when their names suggest. In particular they do not trigger if a change in parent visibility has made you invisible.

There is a `OnParentBecameInvisible` virtual method (with no corresponding event) which does what its name suggests and so fills the gap left by the other two, but it is internal to the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly and so not usable by mere mortals.

(all the above based on reading the .NET 4.8 reference source code)

You might be able to get properly notified if you hook the `VisibleChanged` event on your control and all its parents, but properly maintaining these hooks if you do much control hierarchy rearrangement could be tricky.